# Numpy array - append named column

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy allows me do like this:

```
>>>data = np.genfromtxt(r'd:/temp/data.txt', delimiter = ',', names = True)
>>>data['Time']
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

How can I **make** array like this? I mean to write like:

```
data = np.array([])
data.append(name = 'Time', data = [1., 2., 3.])
data['Time']
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

Comment: Standard disclaimer: recarrays, while handy in some contexts, are substantially underpowered compared to [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) DataFrames.  Data processing is far more convenient with pandas, and you can convert to a recarray at the end if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a [Record Array/Structured Array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), you can checkout [`numpy.core.records.fromrecords`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromrecords.html) -

```
In [35]: data = np.core.records.fromrecords([[1.], [2.], [3.]],names=['Time'])

In [36]: data
Out[36]:
rec.array([(1.0,), (2.0,), (3.0,)],
      dtype=[('Time', '<f8')])

In [37]: data['Time']
Out[37]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
data = numpy.array([(1,), (2,), (3,)], dtype=[('Time', float)])
```

See also this usefull [module](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.recfunctions.html) to manipulate [Record Array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)

Answer (score 0):

`np.core.records` has some nice functions for creating and manipulating structured arrays, but it is also good to know how to construct such arrays from scratch.

Your `genfromtxt` has read from a file with a simple column of string values.  I can recreate it with a list of strings:

```
In [16]: data=np.genfromtxt(['Time','1.','2.','3.'],delimiter=',',names=True)

In [17]: data
Out[17]: 
array([(1.0,), (2.0,), (3.0,)], 
      dtype=[('Time', '<f8')])

In [18]: data['Time']
Out[18]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])

In [19]: data.dtype
Out[19]: dtype([('Time', '<f8')])
```

The key is the `dtype` which is derived from the header, and the appearance of the data.  I'd suggest looking at the `dtype` from more complex `csv` files.

There are various ways of creating a `dtype` from scratch.  One that recreates this case is `dt = np.dtype([('Time',float)])`.

A good way of constructing a similar array is with `np.zeros` (or `np.empty`), specifying the size and the same `dtype`.  Once you have created the array, you can fill in the values field by field.

```
In [20]: data2=np.zeros(3,dtype=data.dtype)

In [21]: data2['Time']=[1,2,3]
```

Another way of creating a structured array is with `np.array`.  The key is that the data has to be provided as a list of **tuples**.

```
In [22]: data1=np.array([(1,),(2,),(3,)],dtype=data.dtype)
```

Looking at the code for `np.core.records.fromrecords` shows a couple of other ways.

In the most general case if fills in the array row by row:

```
In [26]: data3=np.zeros(3,dtype=data.dtype)    
In [27]: for i,v in enumerate([1,2,3]):
   ....:     data3[i]=(v,)
```

And if the fields have all the same dtype, you can just `view` a 2d array with the new `dtype`.

```
In [29]: np.array([1.,2.,3.]).view(data.dtype)
```